# How to get TextRange of text written by user in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textrange

I have RichTextBox which is like "console". In 'cmd' I displaying data from SSH connection and I also allowing to write something into 'cmd' RichTextBox.

```
public void ConnectTTY()
    {
        NewTerminal = new TTY(HostBox.Text, "", LoginBox.Text, PasswordBox.Text);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        ReadStreamAsync(NewTerminal.reader, cmd);

        // cmd is my RichTextBox . At first I am filling it with data from server
        // and in next step I am allowing user to write some command 
        cmd.Focus();


        cmd.CaretPosition = cmd.Document.ContentEnd;
        cmd.ScrollToEnd();

        LastChar =    cmd.Document.ContentEnd ;
    }
```

In last lines I using TextPointer "LastChar" to get position of last added content, because I want to get what user will write in RichTextBox.

On "Enter" event I using ReWriteStream to get last text and send it through SSH.

```
 public void ReWriteStream()
    {

        string myText = new TextRange(LastChar, cmd.Document.ContentEnd).Text ;


        MessageBox.Show("Tekst: " + myText.ToString()  );

        if ( myText.Length != 0 )
        {
            WriteStreamAsync(myText, NewTerminal.writer, NewTerminal.stream);
            ReadStreamAsync(NewTerminal.reader, cmd);

            //WriteStream(myText, NewTerminal.writer, NewTerminal.stream);
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //ReadStream(NewTerminal.reader, cmd);


        }
        cmd.Focus();

    }
```

But every time, my variable myText is empty.

```
string myText = new TextRange(LastChar, cmd.Document.ContentEnd).Text ;
```

How i should get any text, written in my RichTextBox after LastChar position?

Thank You for any help,
Best Regards,
Wiktor

**edit: I have put string into richtextbox to analyze caret position :**

```
public void ConnectTTY()
    {
        NewTerminal = new TTY(HostBox.Text, "", LoginBox.Text, PasswordBox.Text);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        ReadStreamAsync(NewTerminal.reader, cmd);



        cmd.Focus();


        cmd.CaretPosition = cmd.Document.ContentEnd;
        cmd.ScrollToEnd();

        cmd.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("|1|");

        // LastChar = cmd.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;

    }
```

and here :

```
 public void ReWriteStream()
    {
        string caret;
        string myText;



        LastChar = cmd.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);

        cmd.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("|2|");

        myText = new TextRange(LastChar, cmd.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd).Text;
       // myText = new TextRange(LastChar, cmd.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

        MessageBox.Show("Text : " +  myText.ToString()  );

        if ( myText.Length != 0 )
        {
            WriteStreamAsync(myText, NewTerminal.writer, NewTerminal.stream);
            ReadStreamAsync(NewTerminal.reader, cmd);

            //WriteStream(myText, NewTerminal.writer, NewTerminal.stream);
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //ReadStream(NewTerminal.reader, cmd);


        }
        cmd.Focus();

    }
```

And I get exactly what it should be in cmd RichTextBox :
"
You have mail.
-bash-3.2$ 
**|1|** ls -l **|2|**
"

Comment: What type of object is LastChar? a TextPointer? or?

Comment: Yes, it is TextPointer.

Comment: It is TextPointer which I modify only in ConnectTTY() to get ContentEnd position of last "automatically" inserted text into cmd RichTextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to grab the last insertion position, then use that for the text range.

```
public void ReWriteStream()
{
    var myText = new TextRange(rtb.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(0), rtb.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(1) ?? rtb.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd).Text;    
    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, unfortunately it doesn't helped.

Comment: If I use something like this :
` string myText = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text;  `

I can get whole text also that text inserted by user.

Comment: Thank You again for taking time with my problem but again this doesn't help.

Comment: I of course tried:
LastChar = rtb.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
and also  
LastChar = rtb.Document.ContentEnd.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);

Comment: Please take a look on my first post, I insert string "|1|" and "|2|" . Text inserted by user "ls -l" is exactly where it should by. I have no idea why I can't get it in myText variable.

Comment: see the changed answer

Comment: Thank You, it actually help.
I need to understand why ;) 
I will try to make some changes and look what will happen.

Best Regards !